# How to add gallery view with remotevies

Tags: android

I am making android widget.
RemoteViews holds layout which contains LinearLayout.
I want to add Galleryview inside Linear Layout:

```
public class IEGallery extends Gallery {
    public StoryLoader storyListRequest;    
    private ArrayList<Story> storyLists;
    private ImageAdapter storyAdapter;
    private IEGallery _instance;
    Context mcontext;   
    public IEGallery(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        IELog.i("IndianExpress","IEGallery : constructor :: start");
        _instance=this;
}
```

This class return gallery view.I want to add this gallery view in my remoteviews.That is containing Linear Layout .I have write this code but cast problem here.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
IEGallery iegallery =new IEGallery();
views.addView(R.id.llwidgetlist, iegallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add Galleryview inside Linear Layout.

That is not supported by Android. `RemoteViews` does not support `Gallery`. `RemoteViews` does not support any custom subclass of any `View`.

Comment: thank you.Let me know how to get id of the view element from remote view.